# Как изменять элемент в зависимости от значения input с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Возможно в заголовке не получилось передать суть вопроса.
Дело вот в чем. 
Есть текстовые `input`

```
<input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_1">
<input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_2">
```

и есть блок, в который хочу добавлять элементы `span` со значениями этих `input`,

```
<div id="categories"></div>
```

а потом при изменении значения `input` заменять значение элемента, не добавляя новый.
Вот js

```
var category1, category2;

var goodsItem = document.getElementsByClassName('goods-item'); //получаю input

var categOutput = document.getElementById('categories'); //получаю div, куда буду выводить значения input

for ( let i = 0; i < goodsItem.length; i++) {
    goodsItem[i].addEventListener( "change", getCategory);
} //добавляю событие, при котором пользователь вводит что-то в input

function getCategory(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    var span = document.createElement('span'); 

    if (target == goodsItem[0]) {
        category1 = target.value;
        categOutput.appendChild(span);
        span.className = 'class';
        span.innerHTML = category1;
    }
    if (target == goodsItem[1]) {
        category2 = target.value;
        categOutput.appendChild(span);
        span.className = 'class';
        span.innerHTML = category2;
    }
    }
```

в функции пытаюсь, чтобы при срабатывании события на каком-то из `input`, 
создавался в `div` некий `span`, получающий класс `class` и показывающий значение, введенное в `input`
это не важно, но вот стили нового `span`

```
.class {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #C2185B;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 26px;
}
```

По-началу все работает хорошо, но когда я пытаюсь поменять значение, введенное в `input`, срабатывает функция и добавляет новый span.
Я понимаю, почему так происходит, но не могу догнать, как это изменить.
Может кто из тех, кто дочитал до этого места, подскажет?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы по каждому изменению создаете новый элемент, вместо этого можно создать элемент по одному разу для каждого инпута, в этом примере я сохранил ссылки на элементы прямо в инпуте `this.span = ...`, и при следующем вызове проверяю наличие этого поля

```js
var goodsItem = document.getElementsByClassName('goods-item'); 
var categOutput = document.getElementById('categories'); 

for ( let i = 0; i < goodsItem.length; i++) {
    goodsItem[i].addEventListener( "change", getCategory);
} 

function getCategory(event) {
    if (event.target.value === ''){
      this.span.remove();
      delete this.span
      return;
    } 

    if (!this.span) {
      this.span = document.createElement('span'); 
      this.span.className = 'class';
      categOutput.appendChild(this.span);
    }
    this.span.innerHTML = event.target.value;
}
```

```css
.class {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #C2185B;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_1">
<input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_2">
<div id="categories"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает! то есть мы проверяем вначале наличие спан, и если его нет, то создаем, а если есть, то заменяем значение? и получается, что можно вначале написать условие со спаном, а только потом его декларировать?

Comment: @hamster789 первое да, второе не понял

Comment: просто я еще очень плохо шарю, и меня немного смутило, что мы нигде не объявили span, а потом его используем в условии if.

Comment: @hamster789 заменяем значение всегда, а вот создаем только если его еще не было создано и не было присвоено в this

Comment: @hamster789 мы проверяем наличие поля у объекта, для этого его не надо объявлять, его нет и нет сначала

Comment: кажется, дошло, спасибо!

Comment: а теперь еще проблема: когда удаляю все, что было введено в input, этот span остается просто пустым. его можно как-то удалять при пустом input?

Comment: @hamster789 изменил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @hamster789 пожалуйста, обратите внимание на `delete`, вместо него можно было написать `this.span = null`, тогда поле останется, но его проверка все равно вернет `false` т.к. там `null`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var goodsItem = document.getElementsByClassName('goods-item');
var categOutput = document.getElementById('categories');

var span1 = document.createElement('span');
span1.className = 'class';
span1.style.display = 'none';
categOutput.appendChild(span1);

var span2 = document.createElement('span');
span2.className = 'class';
span2.style.display = 'none';
categOutput.appendChild(span2);

for (let i = 0; i < goodsItem.length; i++) {
  goodsItem[i].addEventListener("change", getCategory);
}

function getCategory(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  var span = document.createElement('span');

  if (target == goodsItem[0]) {
    span1.textContent = target.value;
    span1.style.display = span1.textContent == ""? 'none' : '';
  }
  if (target == goodsItem[1]) {
    span2.textContent = target.value;
    span2.style.display = span2.textContent == ""? 'none' : '';
  }
}
```

```css
.class {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #C2185B;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_1">
<input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_2">

<div id="categories"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой оперативный ответ! Действительно заработало, как надо. Только вы не могли бы объяснить, как именно работает строчка span2.style.display = span1.textContent == ""? 'none' : ''; ?

Comment: @hamster789 Если `span` пустой, то его прячем.